# SQLite timestamp field - converting to datetime

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

EDIT

So with the help of [MikeT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744514/miket) this is what I have come up with to convert the **Apple Cocoa Core Data timestamp** values into Unix epoch values:

`SELECT datetime(559951200 + 978307200, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');`

Where `559951200` is my **Apple Cocoa Core Data timestamp**

Then, to get my localtime, I needed to add an additional parameter `localtime` to my `datetime(...)` function in SQLite.

---

I am revieving the sqlite database of my `ScanSnap Home` scanner and document manager for Mac.

It is located in `~/Library/Application Support/PFU/ScanSnap Home/Managed/ScanSnapHome.sqlite`

The database has many tables with timestamp fields in it. I cannot convert those timestamp values to date/time.

For example: I have a date value that I can see in the user interface as `2018-09-30`. That date value translates to `559951200` in the database (timestamp field).

Assuming the number is an epoch value, I try to convert it to a date value via https://www.epochconverter.com But it will give me `September 30, 1987`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your timestamp appears to be an **Apple Cocoa Core Data timestamp**.

By adding **978307200** it converts to an epoch value.

Thus 559951200 + 978307200 = **1538258400** which is epoch time for **Saturday, 29 September 2018 22:00:00** 
- (***GMT*** so local time may well be 30th).

Core Data has a start date of 2001/01/01 rather than 1970/01/01 and thus 978307200 is the number of seconds difference between the two.

Check out [Cocoa Core Data Timestamp Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/coredata)

Comment: Thank you a million times. I would never have found that out in a reasonable time. :)

Comment: The query for this in SQLite is `SELECT *,strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M.%s', TimeField, 'unixepoch', '978307200 seconds') from zTablename `  assuming the data comes from a table managed by core data.